# objective c cocoa updating gui from a separate thread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++

I have a thread which is incrementing the value of the variable  "int count" . I want to update my UI with the new value of  "int count" until I stop the increment by pressing the stop button. I've manage to update the UI but the memory footprint keep on growing. It doesn't show as a memory leak but it is an allocation problem.the heap size is being increased every time there is a call to a UI element from the thread. I can clearly see instruments leaks allocation part that I have some allocations which are only being freed when moving the Window of touching a UI element. I did not manage to solve the problem despite trying everything. 
If there is a better way to update UI elements with "int count" new value, feel free to let me know.
Thanks

I posted the link to the cocoa project below if you want to run with instrument or allocation to see the problem  or look at the source. It' a small project just a few lines.

[Xcode Poject GUI UPDATE  LINK](http://www.mediafire.com/?tqhm248382bjlc3)

```
-(void) incrementCountGUI:(id)param{ // increment count and update gui
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];// pool just added

    count++;
    if (count>=100) {// MAKE SURE COUNT DOESN'T GO ABOVE 100
        count=0;
    }
    [sliderDisplayOutlet setIntValue:count];// display value of count in textfield
    [sliderOutlet setIntValue:count];// move slider to value of count

    [pool release];
}


+(void) updateSliderThread:(id)param{// this thread will call incrementCountGUI method to continuously upgrade UI in the background

    NSAutoreleasePool *myThreadPool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
while (shoudStop==NO) {
    [ sharedAppInstance performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(incrementCountGUI:) // update ui in main thread
                                         withObject:nil
                                      waitUntilDone:NO];
    usleep(5000);// sleep microsec; 
}   
    [myThreadPool release]; 
}

- (IBAction)stopCountAction:(id)sender {// START OR STOP counter thread

    if ([stopCountButtonOutlet state]==1) { // button depressed=>START
        shoudStop=NO;
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateSliderThread:) toTarget:[AppController class] withObject:nil];
        [stopCountButtonOutlet setTitle: @" STOP" ];

    }
    if ([stopCountButtonOutlet state]==0){//button depressed=> STOP thread

        shoudStop=YES;

        [stopCountButtonOutlet setTitle:@" START INCREMENTING COUNT FROM THREAD "];

    }


}

- (IBAction)sliderAction:(id)sender { // you can change the value of the variable count manualy.
 count=[sliderOutlet intValue];
[sliderDisplayOutlet setIntValue:count];// display value of count


}
```

Comment: Why create an auto release pool if you're not going to drain it?

Comment: @bryanmac Standard practice for a new thread. All thread methods should have an autorelease pool. How do you know that performSelectorOnMainThread: doesn't add any autorelease'd objects to the current pool?

Comment: I added an autorelease pool to my method "incrementCountGui" but it has not helped. heap size keep on increasing I can even see it on the activity monitor

Comment: Xcode project link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First of all, you should **never** update the UI from a thread other than the main thread !

_Post a notification to the mainThread to ask it to update the UI, or use `performSelector:onMainThread:` or GCD and `get_main_queue()`, or whatever solution to make the main thread update the UI.

[EDIT] Sorry I missed the part of your code where you call `performSelectorOnMainThread:` so that's OK.

---

2) Moreover, **using a thread for what you need is really not necessary**. In general you should avoid thread, an prefer other techniques like NSOperationQueues, GCD, or even RunLoop scheduling.

In your case, using a thread an usleep(5000) is just overhead and will arise a lot of problems related to multithreading (read Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide and Threading Programming Guide).

**You could do the same thing using a repeating `NSTimer`**, it will be much more easier to code and manage, and will avoid you a lot of trouble.

Comment: The count variable value will be modified by thread or callback function during run time. This is the reason i have to to be able to update the UI regardless of how count has been modified.

Comment: you're right AliSoftware, you pointed me in the right direction with operation queue gcd nstimers.I will do some more reading and rewrite the code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm.. let's try to release behind-the-scene objects created by `performSelectorOnMainThread` calls, if any.

```
+(void) updateSliderThread:(id)param
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *myThreadPool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    int drainCount = 0;   
    while (shoudStop==NO)
    {
        [ sharedAppInstance performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(incrementCountGUI:)
                                             withObject:nil
                                          waitUntilDone:NO];
        usleep(5000);// sleep microsec; 

        // Release pooled objects about every 5 seconds
        if (++drainCount >= 1000)
        {
            [myThreadPool release];
            myThreadPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
            drainCount = 0;
        }
    }   
    [myThreadPool release]; 
}
```

Comment: Just tried it but it does not stop memory footprint from increasing. thanks.